# Step by step guide required on how to integrate revmob local notifications into iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, revmob

I have revmob banners, full screens and popups integrated into my iPhone and iPad apps, with the latest revmob SDK & using placement ID. All are working fine.

I now want to intergate revmob [local notifications](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios#localnotification) into these app as well. I am not a programmer, but am looking for a step by step guide to do this. Please assume the revmob SDK is already working fine in the app.

The revmob 'local notifications' instructions say 2 things:

NUMBER 1:

```
[[RevMobAds session] scheduleLocalNotification];
```

Do you put this into the appdelegate.m file under the line: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

NUMBER 2:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [[RevMobAds session] processLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Do you just copy this all in on its own near the end of the appdelegate.m file?

NUMBER 3: Is there anything else you have to do to set up these local notifications not mentioned on the revmob website?

Currently I have done points 1 & 2 above. When I did number 2 it gave me a warning but the app built ok on my iPhone. Waited 24 hours, local notification did not appear.

I get this output in the simulator:

[RevMob] Requesting local notification data.

[RevMob] [LocalNotification] No Ads available for this device/country at this moment, or your App ID is paused.

Answer (score 1):

The steps number 1 and 2 looks ok, there is no need to step 3.

This message that you are saying indicates that there are no ads for your device (or your app id is paused). Depending on your country and device you could be without ads sometimes.
Do you have another device?

The method "scheduleLocalNotification" schedule the notifications automatically, in a time that RevMob decides to be the best. These days this time is around 5:30pm.

If you want to determine the scheduled time you can use "scheduleLocalNotification:" method, check on the [API documentation site](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/scheduleLocalNotification%3a).

Comment: [[RevMobAds session] scheduleLocalNotification];
is deprecated...what's alternative ?

Comment: So far there aren't alternatives :-/